# rounded CTabFolder since the start of the app

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I have a question concerning ctabfolders in eclipse rcp.
I created an e4 RCP app with a window comprising a stack part container, which contains a stack.
this stack contains 1 part. in this part, there is a ctabfolder and one ctabitem.

when I launch the app via the product file, I see this:
[image]

there are 2 problems:
1. the partCTabFolder appears at the top of the window, and I would like to remove it.
2. the test1 CTabItem is not selected; I disabled the flag "simple" with setSimple(false), so the CTabItem should be displayed with rounded borders, which is not the case until I click on it.
in this case, the window appears like this:
[image]
the problem 1 remains, but the 2nd one is resolved.

I know that part classes are created lazily, but I think it does not apply here since the part is the only one and is displayed as soon as the window is run.

here is the code of the @PostConstruct method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    CTabFolder tabFolder = new CTabFolder(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    tabFolder.setSimple(false);
    tabFolder.setSelectionBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT));

    CTabItem tbtmTest = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmTest.setText("test1");

    Composite composite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmTest.setControl(composite);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);

    Label lblHelloWolf = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblHelloWolf.setText("Hello World!");

}
```

is it possible to get rounded CTabItem borders as soon as the part is displayed?
How to get rid of the "partCTabFolder" text at the top of the window?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The "partCTabFolder" tab is because you have put your part in a 'Part Stack' - the part stack uses tabs for each part. If you don't want this just put your Part directly in the main window or a Part Sash Container.

CTabFolder only draws the full curved tab for the selected part. Other tabs just have to slightly rounded outline. You can make your tab the selected tab initially by calling:

```
tabFolder.setSelection(tbtmTest);
```